# R: Most elegant way to sanitize data frame before pasting all elements to single string

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame similar to below:

```
df.example <- data.frame(c(2:3, NA, "John"), c("Mary", NA, "", NA), c("Dennis", 4:6))

 2     Mary     Dennis
 3     John     4
 <NA>           5      # note the empty string
 John  <NA>     6      # "John" occurs twice
```

I have omitted the row and column names because they contain no useful information.

I would like to convert this to a 1D list, containing ALL values in the data frame, removing `NA` and empty string values. I would like to retain only `unique` values, and concatenate them so I can use them as an argument for a SQL query later in the code.

This is my current solution:

```
temp <- df.example[!is.na(df.example)]

 # "2" "3" "John" "Mary" "John" "" "Dennis" "4" "5" "6"     

temp <- unique(temp[temp != ""])

 # "2" "3" "John" "Mary" "Dennis" "4" "5" "6"     

output <- paste0("'",temp,"'", collapse = ",")

 #"'2','3','John','Mary','Dennis','4','5','6'"
```

Now I can pass this string to SQL.

This seems like way too many lines of code to do what I was expecting to be a one-liner. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Why not just combine all those into a one-liner: `paste0("'", unique(df.example[!is.na(df.example) & df.example != ""]), "'", collapse = ",")`

Comment: Definitely an option, but it's a rather messy line of code. I'm looking for more of a "paste all valid values from data frame" version of `paste`

Comment: Sounds like you might want to write your own function then

Comment: That's what I'm leaning toward at this point, I just wanted to know if there was some small option I had missed which removes `""` and `NA` from the data frame before I wrote my own paste wrapper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Rich Scriven's comment.
However, if you want a one-liner answer perhaps something like:

```
df.example <- data.frame(c(2:3, NA, "John"), c("Mary", NA, "", NA), c("Dennis", 4:6))
names(table(as.vector(t(df.example)),exclude=c("",NA)))
    # [1] "2"      "3"      "4"      "5"      "6"      "Dennis" "John"   "Mary"
```

Comment: Thanks! But why is the transpose necessary?

Comment: Because it was shorter than writing "unlist(df.example, use.names=FALSE)"
the t function transposes the data into a matrix (which is once again shorter than using the "as.matrix" function) and, therefore, can be used in table. The way I understand it, matrices are actually vectors with additional methods. while data.frames are lists. There is further redundancy in my answer. as.vector isn't required. so you can simply use: names(table(t(df.example),exclude=c("",NA)))